# How to add a @command inside the main.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Firstly I am launching the bot using `py -m testbot` as a script

I am trying to add a reload command inside my "bot.py" but decorator is not recognized by default `help` command and of course the command is not available for usage

Below is a quick reference to my `bot.py`'s structure

```py
from discord.ext.commands import Bot as TestBot

class Bot(TestBot):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        super().__init__(
            intents=Intents.all()
            ...
        )

    def run(self):
        ...

    async def on_connect(self):
        ...

    .
    ..
    ...

    @command(name="reloadd", cls=TestBot)
    async def reload_cmd(self, ctx , *, cog):
        self.reload_extension(f"testbot.bot.cogs.{cog}")
        print("{cog} reloaded")
```

Comment: Have you tried `@commands.command()`? Never seen someone using `@command`.

Comment: Did you notice that `reload` is misspelled?  Was that intentional?

Comment: @Dominik `from discord.ext.commands import command`

Comment: @TimRoberts yes it is intentional(there is a command, inside a cog that is named reload) `self.reload_extension` is still valid.

Comment: @Taraxiah There is no such `from discord.ext import command`, it is `from discord.ext import commands`

Comment: @Dominik check my previous reply and try again...

Comment: I see, you use it in a different way, but why? Have you used `print` statements to see where the bot gets stuck?